# Conversion of MLS/AURA RELATIVE HUMIDITY PRODUCT to correctly referenced GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, gdal, remote-sensing, georeferencing, hdf5

I have downloaded the following product

https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/concepts/C1251101764-GES_DISC.html

and it gives me a `.he5`file.
Can anyone help me in correctly geo-referencing the file into a corresponding `GeoTiff` file, so it correctly projects itself in something like QGIS?

There is also an associated `.xml` file with it available to download.

Comment: the xml file probably has the metadata

Comment: yes it does. Do you know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems QGIS (via GDAL) offers limited support for HDF-EOS5 (or HDF5 in general), and there are discussions about the issue in this [GIS-SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=hdf5). You may want to try these suggestions.

---

Let me suggest a workaround using a software [Panoply](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) to get the data out of HDF5 and convert it into CSV. (So that you can read it in QGIS as a delimited text data).

1. Install [Panoply](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/download/) and start it.
2. Open the dataset and select your preferred variable and plot it. (Follow steps 1, 2, 3 below).

[image]

3. You will see a nice plot, but ignore it for the moment and select **Array tab**.

[image]

4. Select and highlight all data, then copy them (e.g. `Ctrl+C` in Windows), then paste the data to a text editor (e.g. Notepad++). Now save the data as a text file.

[image]

5. Start QGIS and read the text file by **Add Delimited Text Layer**.

[image]